# Setting business name and header images with adaptive payments on paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

In order to ensure consistent experience i want to set header image and business on paypal's page, view items with their names and description and ask the customer to select shipping address.

I'm using active_paypal_adaptive_payment gem (https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) and the option to set_payment_options:

```
response = ADAPTIVE_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(
  :action_type => 'CREATE',
  :receiver_list => recipients,
  ...
)

ADAPTIVE_GATEWAY.set_payment_options(
  :display_options => {
    :business_name => 'Big Business',
    :header_image_url => 'url goes here'
  },
  :sender_options => {
    :require_shipping_address_selection => true },
  :receiver_options => [{
    :description => _description,
    :invoice_data => {
      :item => [{ 
        :name => _title, 
        :item_count => 1, 
      }],
      :total_shipping => 10.0,
      :total_tax => 10
    },
    :receiver => { 
      :email => email 
    }
  }])
)
```

The issue is that it doesn't work - i do not see any business names or image, i see generic names on the left column (the one with the items and the flow doesn't ask for shipping address).

[image: paypal-generic-message-no-item-details]

Could you please advise?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do so by logging into PayPal, then going to My Selling Tools and update the *Custom payment pages* option to create a new page style with the color combination and logo of your choice (there are size restrictions for the logo images)